# Selenium - Running tests in parallel locally

Tags: java, selenium, testng

I'm trying to run my selenium tests in parallel locally and by reading online I know I can do so by using TestNG. 
I've got the following sample code which allows me to run 2 tests in parallel.

#### testng.xml

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
<suite name="Parallel" thread-count="2" parallel="methods" >
    <test name="testing">
        <classes>
            <class name="Sessions"/>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

#### Sessions.class

```
@Test
public void testSessionOne() throws IOException {
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("http://www.google.co.uk");
    driver.findElement(By.name("q")).sendKeys("one");
}

@Test
public void testSessionTwo() throws IOException {
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("http://www.google.co.uk");
    driver.findElement(By.name("q")).sendKeys("two");
}
```

This works fine, however I wanted to use a PageObjectModel framework. I've changed the tests slightly so it now looks like this. (I've kept the same testng.xml).

#### Sessions.class

```
public void testSession1() throws IOException{
    WebDriver driver = getDriver();
    open(driver, url);
    enterTextInSearchField(driver, "one");
}
```

#### MyMethods.class

```
public WebDriver getDriver(){
    return new ChromeDriver();
}

public void open(WebDriver driver, String url) {
    driver.get(url);
}

public void enterTextInSearchField(WebDriver driver, String search) {
    driver.findElement(By.name("q")).sendKeys(search);
}
```

The problem I have now is that I need to always pass "driver" as a parameter for all my methods. If I don't, the tests get confused and tries to run everything on the same browser. 
Is there a better way I can do this so I could still be able to run in parallel and not have to pass driver as a parameter?

Answer (score 0):

One of the options that you could look at is to leverage `ThreadLocal` variables wherein either in a `@BeforeMethod` (or) in a `org.testng.IInvokedMethodListener#beforeInvocation()` (or) in a `org.testng.IHookable` implementation you can have your `WebDriver` instantiation taken care of and pushed into a `ThreadLocal` variable which your `@Test` method could pop-out and work with it.

I have explained this in this blog post post of mine. Please see if that helps.

Blog link : https://rationaleemotions.wordpress.com/2013/07/31/parallel-webdriver-executions-using-testng/